# Sin along a vector?

Tags: vectors

I have a 2D vector that I currently use to plot a line in its direction.

I calculate the next point using:

```
p_new = p_old + v * i
```

Were i going from 0 to some upper limit where the line should end, say for example 100.

How would I go about to plot a sin curve in direction *v*?

Comment: By $p_{old}$ and $p_{new}$ do you mean $p_{i+1}$ and $p_i$ so that this is $p_{i+1} = p_i + v \cdot i$?

Comment: Do you mean simply p_new=sin(v*i+p_old)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate the perpendicular $v^{\perp}$ to $v$ and normalize both vectors. Then plot
$$A\sin(\omega t)v^{\perp} + tv$$
for some values of the constants $A$ and $\omega$, which control the amplitude and frequency of the sine wave respectively.